# Identity jump issue in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

does the identity jump issue solved in sql server 2012 SP1 or SP2 ?
what is the best way to workaround the jumping

Comment: Are you sure you have registered -t272 to SQL Server Startup Parameter correctly? http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/668042/SQL-Server-Auto-Identity-Column-Value-Jump-Is

Comment: I have not noticed this problem on any SQL Server 2012 installation. They all have either SP1 or SP2.